# C++ homework assistance

Tags: c++, debugging

I have an assignment and could use some help with it. I am not sure how to edit it so that it works correctly.

Here is my assignment.

> Example 10-10 defined a class `personType` to store the name of a person. The member functions that we included merely print and set the name of a person. Redefine the class `personType` so that, in addition to what the existing class does, you can:
>
> - Set the first name only.
> - Set the last name only.
> - Store and set the middle name.
> - Check whether a given first name is the same as the first name of this person.
> - Check whether a given last name is the same as the last name of this person.
>
> Write the definitions of the member functions to implement the operations for this class. Also, write a program to test various operations on this class.

I am not sure how to get these to work.

`isFirstName` correctly determines if a name is a student's first name.

`isLastName` correctly determines if a name is a student's first name.

These ones work:

- The program can initialize a `personType` object without error.
- `personType` getters and setters work as expected.

---

Here is my code that I have so far.

*Main.cpp*:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "personType.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    personType student = personType("Jane","Sarah","Doe");

    //e. Check whether a given last name is the same as the last name of this person.
    if (student.isFirstNameSame("Jane")) {
        cout<<"First name is the same"<<endl;
    }
    else {
        cout<<"First name is not same"<<endl;
    }

    //e. Check whether a given last name is the same as the last name of this person.
    if (student.isLastNameSame("Wood")) {
        cout<<"Last name is not the same"<<endl;
    }
    else {
        cout<<"Last name is not same"<<endl;
    }
}
```

*PersonType.h*:

```cpp
#ifndef PERSONTYPE_H
#define PERSONTYPE_H

#include <string>

class personType {
public:
    personType(std::string fname = "",std::string lname = "",std::string mname = "");
    //a. Set the first name only.
    void setFirstName(std::string);
    //b. Set the last name only.
    void setLastName(std::string);
    //c. Store and set the middle name.
    void setMiddleName(std::string);


    bool isFirstNameSame(const std::string&);
    bool isLastNameSame(const std::string&);

    std::string getFirstName() const;
    std::string getLastName() const;
    std::string getMiddleName() const;

    //Class member variables must be implemented as private.
private:
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    //c. Store and set the middle name.
    std::string middleName;
};

#endif
```

*personTypeImp.cpp*:

```cpp
#include <string>

#include "personType.h"

using std::string;

personType::personType(std::string fname,std::string lname,std::string mname)
{
    firstName = fname;
    lastName = lname;
    middleName = mname;
}

void personType::setFirstName(std::string fname)
{
    firstName = fname;
}

void personType::setLastName(std::string lname)
{
    lastName = lname;
}

void personType::setMiddleName(std::string mname)
{
    middleName = mname;
}

//Functions in exercise 9 d. and e. must return a
//boolean indicating whether the specified names are identical or not.
bool personType::isFirstNameSame(const std::string& fname)
{
    return firstName.compare(fname) == 0;
}

//Functions in exercise 9 d. and e. must return a
//boolean indicating whether the specified names are identical or not.
bool personType::isLastNameSame(const std::string& lname)
{
    return lastName.compare(lname) == 0;
}

std::string personType::getFirstName() const
{
    return firstName;
}

std::string personType::getLastName() const
{
    return lastName;
}

std::string personType::getMiddleName() const
{
    return middleName;
}
```

Comment: `isFirstNameSame` and `isLastNameSame` both work as expected.

Comment: Please update the code in the question so that it shows code does not work as expected and explain what is the wrong behavior there and what should happen instead.

Answer (score 2):

The class works fine. If you want to be able to set the first and last name only once you can do like this:

```
void personType::setFirstName(std::string fname){
   if (firstName == "")
       firstName = fname;
}
```

and the same for the last name.

To test, add in `main`:

```
    personType student2 = personType("John");
    student2.setFirstName("Oleg"); // doesn't set
    if(student2.isFirstNameSame("Jane")){
        cout<<"First name is the same "<< student2.getFirstName() <<endl;
    }else{
        cout<<"First name is not same "<< student2.getFirstName() << endl;
    }
  
    student2.setLastName("Smith");
    if(student2.isLastNameSame("Smith")){
        cout<<"Last name is the same "<< student2.getLastName() <<endl;
    }else{
        cout<<"Last name is not same "<< student2.getLastName() <<endl;
    }
```

Comment: Where does the assignment say that you can only/should set the name once?

Comment: And the question also says `personType getters and setters work as expected.`

Comment: @t.niese just in case the "Set the first name only" and "Store and set the middle name" means different things.

Comment: @t.niese the assignment doesn't say that we can set it only once but practically, it makes sense to be able to set them only once.

Comment: @RamPrabodhInduri That's something that should be clarified using the comment section. Besides that why should it that make no sense: Last names can change and mistakes can happen. Having a setter, especially one that silently fails to set something makes no sense.

Comment: Well think about it, why should setting a name fail in the first place, you can need someone anything?? So you can name him/her 12345 for all the program is concerned or peter white.

Comment: I really don't care about if it is logic or not. I think the situation could be required just to learn how to set a property only once (this is an assignment after all.) In any case, just ignoring that characteristic if it isn't needed is enough, and with it he has more info.